# Indentation Error in python 3.6

Tags: python

When i run this code in IDLE, i get a SyntaError(expected an indent block)
The thing is that i dont see any indentation problem.
What the code does:
It reads 'cities.txt' file(with string lines)
It then copies those lines in 'out.txt', after enumeration in each line

```
try:
    with open('cities.txt', 'r+') as inp:
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File not found')
except:
    print('Error')
else:
    try:
        with open('out.txt', 'a+') as out:
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found')
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        for i, line in enumerate(inp):
            out.write(str(i+1)+': '+line)
            print(str(i+1)+': '+line, end='\n')
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Check the formatting of your code in your question (look at the editing tools available at the top of the editing window to quote source code.)

Comment: Also turn on the option in your IDE (if there is one) to display visible whitespace so you can see the actual indentation characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure logic and format, you should write your code like this :

```
try:
    with open('out.txt', 'a+') as out:
        for i, line in enumerate(inp):
            out.write(str(i+1)+': '+line)
            print(str(i+1)+': '+line, end='\n')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File not found')
except:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wasn't sure i could do that, but I wanted to try and use 2 different try-blocks

Answer (score 2):

`with x as y:` should be followed by an indented code block that does what you want with the resource - basically what you now have in the else block

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's my first week in python.